# Incorrect Java coverage analysis result when executing the analysis via Jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We run Sonar coverage analysis for multi-module Java projects in a Jenkins environment using the sonar-maven-plugin. We noticed that the coverage analysis results displayed on our Sonar dashboard are not correct for a handful of source files. One odd finding from my investigation is that I when I run the analysis from my local development laptop, the coverage analysis is correct (Sonar dashboard updated with the correct coverage percentages for those source files). Has anyone encountered any issues like this before?

Clarification:

The differences in the coverages are mostly between 0 and non-zero percent coverage. But I also see a couple of instances where the difference is between non-zero and non-zero percent coverage. Also, the differences correspond to source files from random packages, not any specific package. We are encountering this issue across various Sonar projects as well (so not just an issue specific to one of our Sonar project).

Also, when I import the Jacoco exec data file into Eclipse (using eclemma plugin), I do see the correct coverage percentages (non-zero). Furthermore, the coverage result when running the analysis locally can also be incorrect when compared with the result as interpreted by the EclEmma plugin). So, now it seems the analysis results may be incorrect regardless of which environments I run the analysis from (assuming the analysis result from EclEmma is correct).

Not sure why the coverage results is wrong only for a handful of the source files. I have compared both the client-side console logs and server side (Sonar server) logs -- but did not find any clues (no indication of error, both analysis were successful). I have also compared the coverages-xxx.pb files' sizes from the batch-report folder, but did not find any differences either.

Thanks in advance to anyone with suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this further! Please let me know if any additional information regarding the execution environments would be helpful.

Thanks,
Thinh

SONAR ENVIRONMENT:
- sonar-maven-plugin version: 3.3.0.603
- SonarQube version: 5.6.6
- sonar.java.source: 1.8
- sonar.java.target: 1.8
- sonar.sourceEncoding: UTF-8

SonarQube plugins:
- Findbugs 3.5 (findbugs)
- SonarJava 4.11.0.10660 (java)
- Git 1.2 (scmgit)

JENKINS ENVIRONMENT:
 - Jenkins version: CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.46.3.2-rolling 
 - Maven version: 3.1.1 
 - Java version: OpenJDK 64-bit Server 1.8.0_141
 - Slave OS: 64-bit, CentOS (Red Hat 4.4.7-11), Linux version
   2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64

LOCAL LAPTOP ENVIRONMENT:
 - Maven version: 3.1.1 
 - Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
   (build 1.8.0_60-b27) 
 - OS: macOS Sierra, version 10.12.5

Comment: Please [edit] your question to more fully describe the differences you see. Is it the difference between 0 and non-zero, or something else? Also, are these files grouped together in the same package or scattered randomly throughout your project?

Comment: Thank you for your response, G. Ann. I have updated the question to include these clarifications -- The differences in the coverages are mostly between 0 and non-zero percent coverage. But I also see a couple of instances where the difference is between non-zero and non-zero percent coverage. Also, the differences correspond to source files from random packages, not any specific package. We are encountering this issue across various Sonar projects as well (so not just an issue specific to one of our Sonar project).

Comment: Also, when I import the Jacoco exec data file into Eclipse (using eclemma plugin), I do see the correct coverage percentages (non-zero).

Comment: Examined the data some more --- the coverage result when running the analysis locally can also be incorrect when compared with the result as interpreted by the EclEmma plugin). So, now it seems the analysis results may be incorrect regardless of which environments I run the analysis from (assuming the analysis result from EclEmma is correct).